# Laravel 4 Eloquent - how to get object properties

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have two models, Topic Model and a Post Model. A Topic can have multiple posts.

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('FPost');
}
```

Now to get the latest post for a topic I am doing something like the following

```
public function latestPost()
{
    return $this->posts()->where('f_topic_id',"=",$this->id)->take(1);

}
```

and then I am getting the latest post attributes as such (for a particular topic)

```
{{$topic->latestPost()->first()['title']}}
```

Now , I have tried enough , but it seems that this is not working for me

```
{{$topic->latestPost()->first()->title}}
```

my question is why can't i get the properties of the post model ?

**Update..** 
The topic model looks like this

```
class FTopic extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable =['topictitle','topicdescription'];

    public function forumCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('FCategory');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('FPost');
    }

    public function latestPost()
    {
        return $this->posts()->where('f_topic_id',"=",$this->id)->take(1);

    }




    public $rules = [
        'topictitle' => 'required|min:10',
        'topicdescription' => 'required|max:10'
    ];

    public  $errors;

    public function isValid()
    {
        $validation = Validator::make($this->attributes, $this->rules);
        if($validation-> passes())
            return true;
        $this->errors = $validation->messages();
        return false;
    }







    protected $table = 'ftopics';



}
```

**Update 2**
This is how I am using it. 
[image: Usage]
thanks

Comment: Where is `latestPost` declared and what is `$this->posts()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `latestPost` method to:

```
public function scopeLatestPost($query)
{
    return $this->posts()->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}
```

Then use something like this:

```
$ptitle = FTopic::find(1)->latestPost()->first()->title;
```

Comment: I am getting this error message : Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Unfortunately there was a typo, updated it, try again :-

Comment: Nope .. I am still getting the same message. Please note that I have updated the question with a snapshot of the page where the error is happening. thanks

Comment: Does this work `FTopic::find(1)->latestPost()->first()->title` ?

Comment: Then you are probably making any mistakes, don't know what.

Comment: Make sure every topic has posts, maybe some topics don't have any posts yet.